# Summing normal instead of beta distributions, consequences for the density function of the sum?

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, beta-distribution

**Background:**
I've modeled a project effort prediction as a Google Spreadsheet template. Details of the Model: http://sites.google.com/site/effortprediction/methodology
.Google Spreadsheet does not implement beta distribution functions.
In PERT a beta distribution is used to estimate the effort of a task in Ideal Person Days (i.e.: one worker 8h a day without distraction).

**Problem:**
What consequences has use of normal distributions instead of beta distributions when the distribution are summed up to a single distribution.

**Details**
A *project* consists of a list of *tasks*. Each task is *beta distributed* and *independed*, the sum of the tasks therefore should obey to the *central limit theorem*. The *project* therefore is normal distributed. How does Expected Value and SD change for the project when I use normal instead of beta distributions for each task?
I assume that the tasks distribution is skewed more often to the right than to the left.

**Questions**

- Are the tails fater?
- Is the Expected Value higher or lower
  with normal distributions?
- Is the dispersion higher or lower?

Comment: If you match the mean and variance of each task with the normal distribution, then the expected value and standard deviation of the sum is unchanged.  You will loose all information about skewness though - and tails are likely to be thinner with normal

Comment: mean sounds correct, but not sure with beta, i forgot to say how i calculate sd. I start form 90% confidence interval and mean. now i calculate the sd from a norm dist via z-score for 90%. here an error should already be introduced. but what can I say about the error of sd in comparision with beta-dist?

Comment: so you don't have a "standard deviation" specified, you have specified the quantiles - 5% and 95% I take it.  But in this case - if you use a beta distribution to fit the quantiles, and then use a normal to approximate that beta distribution, my comment above applies.

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what you're trying to do? If you're summing beta-distributed random variables and want to know and calculate quantities of the distribution of the sum, there is no way those would be beta-distributed when you were done. So, in that context, it would seem that whether or not Google Spreadsheet had functions for the beta distribution would be irrelevant.

Comment: Also, it seems a little strange to use the beta distribution for a random variable with units of *days*. The beta distribution is concentrated on $[0,1]$, so are all tasks *guaranteed* to be completed in less than one ideal person day? Even if rescaled, it seems the upper bound is a strong assumption.

Comment: @probabilityislogic I get it, SD is SD - logic. but the skewness of the beta-dists will dissapear due the central limit theorem, right? With say 20 tasks normal is good approximated? and for the tails too?

Comment: @cardinal the PERT distribution is a version of beta and used to estimate durations of tasks http://www.vosesoftware.com/ModelRiskHelp/index.htm#Distributions/Continuous_distributions/PERT_distribution.htm

Comment: @cardinal Its not about normalized distribution. My concern is if I distort the information in the input variables for each task (5% Quantile-Average-95% Quantile) Project=Sum (Task). Project is clearly not beta-distributed due Central Limit Theorem. but what do I distord if Tasks are Norm not Beta? As a result I need P(Project< x days) and the worst thing that can happen is that its way too high. So if tails estimated too small i have a problem

Comment: An exponential distribution may be a better idea for modeling instead of the beta distribution.  one because it is highly right skewed, two because it is always positive, three because it has "fat tails", and four because the sum of exponentially distributed quantities has an Erlang or gamma or scaled chi-square distribution - which is no more difficult to handle than a normal, plus it is precise.  And exponential arises as a limiting form of a beta distribution.  Also exponential has maximum entropy (uncertainty) for a given mean - so you only need to ask for expected time to complete

Comment: (cont'd) - expectations are much easier to get accurately compared to "tail behaviour" prior information.  One intuition is usually not too good with extreme parts of a distribution

Comment: @probabilityislogic ad 4) I always suspected that a 'project' is also skewed, experience tells that its real effort exceed the expected in multiples but it's unlikelier to end much sooner. There is a steepness before the expected value and a long tail after. At least thats the intuition. I have to study your suggestion in depth. I see its hard to understand what distribution is right. I wonder if there is a common procedure I should follow...

Comment: @probabilityislogic maximum entropy,... really interesting stuff.

Comment: In my opinion MaxEnt is the best general method for setting up models, and for setting up prior probabilities.  Its a very good "ambiguity resolver" - as is the theory of transformation groups.

Comment: @probabilityislogic reseached exponential distribution, problem: memorylessness . what finishes a task is work (effort, in my model), the more work the higher the probability of being finished. exponential distr would mean regardless of effort invested the probability of finishing is the same. Now thats fatalistic. Maybe its Weibull...

Comment: @roland - the "memoryless" property is a bit confusing because it is conditional, not absolute.  More work/effort would result in a higher rate parameter, and thus a smaller amount of time to finish a project.  the memorylessness would be assessed by looking at the distribution of the "late tasks".  Now why would a task be "late"?  One way I can think of is that the amount of work required to finish it was under-specified - adding in these additional tasks - seems like we are back to the start - so memorylessness may be a good property.

Comment: (cont'd) the memorylessness can be seen as incorporating a degree of "things not planned for" in the tasks - where we expect the things not planned for to be of a similar size to the things which were planned for

Comment: @probabilityislogic I understand your point, now I will study exponential distribution and eventually build a new model based on it. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go ahead and calculate a random uniform, then use the inverse cdf method (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) to get a random Beta. Here is the formula for the inverse beta cdf: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/betainv.html

If you truly want to just not calculate the beta random number, you can be comfortable that beta converges to normal asymptotically, however the folks at PERT feel very strongly that the normal is not appropriate and list several reasons at http://laserlightnetworks.com/Documents/Modeling%20Schedule%20Uncertainty%20without%20Monte%20Carlo%20Methods.pdf

They suggest the triangle distribution is a better approximation because of steeper decent in cdf and defined support, whereas normal has tails that go to infinity, the triangle and beta distributions have fixed range.

Comment: Your idea is great and I will take it into consideration. But I tried also to make my question valuable for others by abstracting from my case and comparing normal with beta distribution. So I believe your answer is more a "comment" than a real answer. A moderator might explain if I am right or not. I just don't want to be selfish and adhere to the spirit of stackexchange...